# Very simple pygame grid program, How do I get the boxes around the clicked grid to behave appropriately when clicked near sides or corners?

Tags: python, grid, pygame

So here is what I have so far...

```
import pygame


BLACK    = (   0,   0,   0)
WHITE    = ( 255, 255, 255)
GREEN    = (   0, 255,   0)
RED      = ( 255,   0,   0)


width  = 20
height = 20


margin = 5

grid = []
for row in range(10):

    grid.append([])
    for column in range(10):
        grid[row].append(0) 

pygame.init()


size = [255, 255]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)



done = False


clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#Main Program Loop
while done == False:
    for event in pygame.event.get(): 
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
            done = True
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:

            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

            column = pos[0] // (width + margin)
            row = pos[1] // (height + margin)

            grid[row][column] = 1
            grid[row+1][column+1] = 1
            grid[row-1][column-1] = 1
            grid[row-1][column] = 1
            grid[row+1][column] = 1
            grid[row][column+1] = 1
            grid[row][column-1] = 1
            grid[row-1][column+1] = 1
            grid[row+1][column-1] = 1

            print("Click ", pos, "Grid coordinates: ", row, column)

    # Set the screen background
    screen.fill(BLACK)


    for row in range(10):
       for column in range(10):
            color = WHITE
            if grid[row][column] == 1:
                color = RED
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,
                             color,
                             [(margin+width)*column+margin,
                              (margin+height)*row+margin,
                              width,
                              height])


    clock.tick(90)



    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Now, When I click anywhere near the edges or the corners, It goes on to the opposite side of the grid and when I click directly in the corners the program crashes. Any ideas? How do I get it to appropriately work when clicked on the corners and the edges? Thanks

Comment: Note that in Python an index of `-1` means the last item in the sequence...

Answer (score 0):

Your code simply doesn't handle any special cases.

It goes on to the opposite when your row or column equals to 0 and you subtract 1 from it.
It happens because, as [jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe) commented, an index of -1 stands for the last item.
So grid[-1][-1] means grid[9][9].
The simplest way to fix it is adding some if statements where necessary, for example:

```
if row > 0 and column > 0:
     grid[row-1][column-1] = 1
```

The program crashes showing a very specific error:

> IndexError: list index out of range

It is very similar to the previous problem, only this time when you choose row == 9 or column == 9 the program also tries to access grind[row + 1][x] or grind[x][column + 1] which doesn't exist.
So you need to check if it's not the last index as well:

```
if row < 9 and column < 9:
     grid[row+1][column+1] = 1
```

So this is your simple fix:

```
grid[row][column] = 1
if row < 9 and column < 9:
    grid[row+1][column+1] = 1
if row > 0 and column > 0:
    grid[row-1][column-1] = 1
if row > 0:
    grid[row-1][column] = 1
if row < 9:
    grid[row+1][column] = 1
if column < 9:
    grid[row][column+1] = 1
if column > 0:
    grid[row][column-1] = 1
if row > 0 and column < 9:
    grid[row-1][column+1] = 1
if row < 9 and column > 0:
    grid[row+1][column-1] = 1
```